# Using an if statement in a variable in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use an if statement in a variable in wordpress such that if the `page-id is 17711` the variable should be equal to 4 if not true is should be equal to `intval( get_option('wp_estate_prop_no', '') );`

The code i am trying to use is:

```
$prop_no   =   if (is_page(17711)) { 4}
               else {
                   intval( get_option('wp_estate_prop_no', '') );
                   }
```

Comment: use ternary operator ?: or assign it to variable and then use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unsure what your `is_page` function does, but you should be able to use [PHP's ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to achieve an identical effect.

`$prop_no = (is_page(17711) ? 4 : intval( get_option('wp_estate_prop_no', '')));`

Comment: Happy to help @user38208 . Since your issue is resolved, please upvote and accept my answer so people know your problem was fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $prop_no = (is_page(17711)?4:intval(get_option('wp_estate_prop_no,''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about here : https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples 
yo can use `$proper_no = is_page(17711) ? 4 : intval( get_option('wp_estate_prop_no', ''));`

or.

```
if(is_page(17711) == 4){
     $proper_no = 4;
    }else{
    $proper_no = get_option('wp_estate_prop_no', '');
}
```